# Lens Shape in CSS

Tags: css, css-transforms, css-shapes

I am attempting to draw a lens shape with CSS, of a certain height and width. In order to produce a continuous curvature, the border radius of the top left and bottom right corners must be 100% and the other corners, 0%. This produces a lens at an angle of 45 degrees. Because it is at this angle, I cannot increase the height or width of the lens individually, without distorting it.

I have experimented with transformations, but the browser always applies the rotation before the scale, so it does not work.

Is there a way I can change the height and width of the lens individually?

I have created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HYSLf/2/) to illustrate what I mean.
Shape 1 is the right height, but does not have continuous curvature.
Shape 2 has continuous curvature, but is not the right shape.
Shape 3 is my attempt at correcting these problems, but which does not work due to the order in which the transformations are being applied:

```
transform: rotate(45deg) scaleY(1.4);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply flip the properties around to determine in which order they are applied:

```
transform: scaleY(1.4) rotate(45deg);
```

[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HYSLf/4/).

Comment: Wow, that makes me feel rather stupid - I hadn't even thought that maybe the order was the reverse of what I had assumed. Thanks!

Comment: Don't feel stupid - it's just one of those "D'oh" moments everybody has. Glad to help you out!